# EWS WebCredentials

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am using the EWS Java Api to connect to the Exchange server here at work. I connect just fine, but I have an issue w/how I connect to the server.

```
 public WebCredentials(String userName, String password, String domain) { ... }
 public WebCredentials(String userName, String password) { ... }
```

These are the only two constructors for logging into the server. Both use strings for the password field. Speaking on the level of security, anyone trying to hack the application will see the password in plain text, no? Since strings are not immediately collected by the GC, there's no way for me to obfuscate the password in these instances, is there? The password is not stored in plain text in my code, but at the point that I create a webcredential object, the password is there plain as day, no?

Comment: so you want to know if someone can see/catch your credentials on creating or not ?

Comment: Yes... does the string that I pass to the constructor stay visible in memory?

Comment: i don´t really know, but if i saw it correctly i think the password changes into a `SecureString`  but as i said i think.

Comment: Since the string is immutable, and since I have to pass it a string, then it doesn't matter if it changes to a `SecureString`, does it?

Comment: probably not but what other possibilitys do you have ?

Comment: I don't, but that seems rather stupid to setup the security for the exchange server as such

Answer (score 0):

[Authentication and EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/dn626019(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Basic authentication disadvantages:

- Requires your application to collect and store the user’s
  credentials.
- You have to turn off NTLM authentication for all users    to use
  basic authentication.
- If a security breach occurs in your       application, it can expose
  the user’s email address and password to      the attacker.

So the one thing you could do is to use an other authentication method for better security.